# Execution time to be printed in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I've created a loan calculator using Javascript. But I've been thinking of adding the time taken for the code to execute the results. I wanted the execution time to be printed in my html page but I have no idea how to go forth. Please help!!!
This is the code of loan calculator:
https://github.com/gerhynes/loan-calculator

I've tried it by console logging the  execution time but it didn't go as expected but I wanted it to be printed in my html.

Comment: If you can, add the necessary code snippets within your question. Asking people to refer to an external link may reduce your chances of a quick and easy answer.

Comment: Okay I will add

Answer (score 0):

```
let LogStarts = performance.now();

loanCalculator();   // <---- The function you're measuring time

let LogEnds = performance.now();
console.log("Loan Calculator took " + (LogEnds - LogStarts) + " milliseconds.");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply